# Facing Issue with Maven custom archtype

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-archetype

I'm trying to generate custom maven archtype, I'm trying below example to generate custom maven spring boot archtype:

[Custom Maven Archtype](https://github.com/Romeh/spring-boot-quickstart-archtype.git)

If I try to run the below maven generate command - works good

```
mvn archetype:generate \
     -DarchetypeGroupId=com.romeh.spring-boot-archetypes \
     -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-quickstart \
     -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 \
     -DgroupId=com.test \
     -DartifactId=sampleapp \
     -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
     -DinteractiveMode=false
```

But if I change the Group ID with my custom name - it started failing
For example if I change this **from** -DarchetypeGroupId=com.romeh.spring-boot-archetypes **to** -DarchetypeGroupId=com.**test**.spring-boot-archetypes

I'm getting below error message - if I change the group id.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:26 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-19T11:45:36-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project spring-boot-quickstart: The desired archetype does not exist (com.test.spring-boot-archetypes:spring-boot-quickstart:1.0.0) -> [Help 1]
```

Please note that - before executing this command I've changed group id in pom.xml and archetype-catalog.xml as well.

Can you please help me to fix this issue - not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Has your custom archetype been installed in your local maven repository?

Answer (score 0):

You just should not do that. These properties

```
 -DarchetypeGroupId=com.romeh.spring-boot-archetypes  
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-quickstart  
 -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0
```

identifies the archetype; it's like when you have some JAR and you want to add it to your project you need to provide `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`.

The same approach is used for archetypes! Archetypes are packaged up in a JAR and they consist of the archetype metadata which describes the contents of the archetype.

Those properties say Maven what archetype (like what JAR) it should run to generate your app skeleton. And if you change them - Maven won't just find the appropriate JAR in the repository.

Instead, you should modify:

```
-DgroupId=com.test 
-DartifactId=sampleapp 
-Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Those will be properties of your project generated by that archetype.